# Intercepting method calls in java osgi

Tags: java, osgi, aspectj, aspect

I'm currently working on a backup and restore mechanism for an OSGi (java) based platform and would like to do the following

BUNDLE A - Some package:

```
void methodDefinedByInterface(Class1 a, Class2 b){
    ...
}
```

I'd like to be able to add something like an annotation to this method as follows:

```
@Backup
void methodDefinedByInterface(Class1 a, Class2 b){
    ...
}
```

So that I can gather the class + method information and also the variable data itself in another bundle so I can back that data up, "Method call on class blabla in package blabla with parameters .. .. ..".

Is this possible within OSGi? I've read up on AspectJ but most information I found seemed quite dated. Or can I add an implementation to the target platform?

Answer (score 1):

See the Weaving Hook specification in the OSGi Core spec. You can implement the hook and weave your annotations into loaded classes as well as add the necessary dynamic import package statements to that the classes have visibility to the package(s) containing your annotations.

Comment: I think the question was more about if this is possible at compile time, instead of a at runtime solution. Would it be possible to add a annotation implementation to the target platform, an thus making it accessible for developers to use it without having to import it into their bundles?

Comment: Compile time has nothing to do with the OSGi framework (runtime). Of course a tool can modify the code including the bundle's manifest. The mention of AspectJ and adding to the target platform lead me to believe the question was about a runtime weaving problem.